Gerúndio em português. Contextos onde não se pode usar o gerúndio em português?
Há algum contexto em que não se possa usar o gerúndio em português?

Infinitos. :-) O que você tem em mente, qual o contexto ou tipo de construção? A pergunta não está clara. Em tempo: Boas-vindas ao Portuguese SE!

É mais fácil você perguntar quando é que usamos o gerúndio em português.
